# every command begin with npm has issue

Tags: npm, npm-install

Here is my problem,
I think I made mistake by adding proxy settings in a wrong way,
now every command begin with `npm` does not work.
here is a pic of the error:
[image]

```
λ npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
    Error: Failed parsing JSON config key "proxy: "="'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080'"
        at parseField (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:376:13)
        at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Conf.add (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)
        at ConfigChain.addString (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
        at Conf.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:316:10)
        at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
        at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
    Error: Failed parsing JSON config key "proxy: "="'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080'"
        at parseField (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:376:13)
        at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Conf.add (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)
        at ConfigChain.addString (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
        at Conf.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:316:10)
        at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
        at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you set your `proxy` setting in a similar way to the registry setting you show: Delete the `proxy` line in your `.npmrc` file and try again. The `.npmrc` file can be found in [the four places listed in the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/npmrc#files). In most cases, you'll find the one with the `proxy` entry in `~/.npmrc`.

Comment: Thank you Trott, I just found the file which has proxy data, and I delete the file content and its working fine now :)